# Git diff HEAD and HEAD~ difference

Tags: git

I was searching on doing a diff between working tree and last commit and came across this accepted answer at Stackoverflow.

Can someone explain what HEAD and HEAD~ is actually referring to as it wasn't explained in the answer and I can't figure it out from google.  :)

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, to factually answer the initial need : "I was searching on doing a diff between working tree and last commit"

You'd have to simply

```
git diff HEAD
```

(`HEAD` is implied for most commands but `diff` is a bit different here, and yes `git diff` is different from `git diff HEAD`)

---

Now, the difference between `HEAD` and `HEAD~` is quite simple :

`HEAD` is the pointer git uses to represent the current state being worked on, often a branch. (see the [glossary](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddefHEADaHEAD))

`~` means the designated commit's *parent*. So `HEAD~` means "not last commit but the one before that"

With such a tree :

```
---> time direction this way --->

A---B---C <<< master <<< HEAD
```

`HEAD` would resolve to commit `C`, while `HEAD~` would resolve to `B`

---

Edit to clarify about `HEAD^`

`HEAD^` and `HEAD~` both point (if we stick to our example) to `B`, but it shouldn't mislead you into thinking they're the same.

`<someCommit>^N` (where `N=1` if not explicitly given) means the designated commit's *Nth parent* when said commit has multiple parents. For a classic two parents merge, if `HEAD` points to the merge commit, parents can be found with `HEAD^` and `HEAD^2`.

`<someCommit>~N`(again, `N` defaulting to 1) , in the other hand, means *Nth ancestor* of said commit, meaning you go back N commits in the past, following only one parent each time. For better clarity, in our example, `HEAD~2` would designate `A`