# See the latest changes of a git pull?

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

When I ran `git pull`, I saw this on the terminal:

```
Fast-forward
 src/components/Button/index.tsx |    2 +-
```

How can I see what the changes are, without having to go to the browser? Is it possible to know what has been changed in the editor (I'm using vscode)?

Comment: if you fetch instead of pull, you can probably make use of https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_85#_incomingoutgoing-changes

Answer (score 1):

You can find the difference by using the command:

```sh
git diff HEAD^1
```

More information about the above `git` command is available in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57889155/4240137), or the man-page for [`git diff`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) is another option.

> Is it possible to know what has been changed in the editor (I'm using vscode)?

To complete the answer, there is an extension available in VSCode that is called [GitLens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens) that provides insightful information about latest commits and changes on a line-by-line basis. There are more details on the above link to the extension.

Comment: I assume you're using OhMyZsh, and in that case [this Git issue](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/issues/449#issuecomment-1459537) says to escape it. Please try `git diff HEAD\^1`, or alternatively `git diff HEAD~1` should produce a similar result.

Answer (score 1):

You can view how your head commit was updated using the reflog :

```
$ git reflog
46f6744 (HEAD -> master, origin/master) HEAD@{0}: pull (finish): returning to refs/heads/master
46f6744 (HEAD -> master, origin/master) HEAD@{1}: pull (start): checkout 46f6744b780c1df8b0212fd297679719443874a3
e5eee0e HEAD@{2}: commit: some message
ac32fe4 HEAD@{3}: commit: some other message
...
```

As you can see : given the above reflog, the effect of `git pull` was to move `HEAD` from commit `e5eee0e` to `46f6744`.

You can then view the diff between these two commits :

```
git diff e5eee0e 46f6744
# if you are interested in this specific file :
git diff e5eee0e 46f6744 -- src/components/Button/index.tsx
```

The `HEAD@{xx}` mentioned in the reflog is also a valid way to specify a commit :

```
git diff HEAD@{2} HEAD
```

These commands can be run from any terminal.

---

Note that `HEAD@{2}` may not the correct reference to look at in your case :
I have `pull (start): ...` and `pull (finish): ...` entries in my example because I configured `pull.rebase = true` on my machine ; if the pull hadn't been a fast forward, the reflog would have registed a sequence of commits being replayed, and the "previous" state could have been `HEAD@{5}` or `HEAD@{11}` or ...

Inspect your reflog to understand which was the active commit before your `git pull` action.

Another place of interest can be the reflog for the remote branch :
it will show you how your local view of `origin/master` was updated when you ran `git pull`

```
$ git reflog origin/master
46f6744 (HEAD -> master, origin/master) refs/remotes/origin/master@{0}: pull: fast-forward
e5eee0e refs/remotes/origin/master@{1}: pull: fast-forward
```

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio Code, there are some extensions which will show you the specific files that changed in a tree view, and allow you to open them in a "diff view" where it shows you the original file on the left, and the updated file on the right, with green/red highlighting of the things that changed.

A few top extensions with this capability:

- GitLens

  - opens a tree view in the side bar with commit and file information
  - adds inline "code lens" comments about recent changes to specific lines
- Git Graph

  - Opens a separate window that shows a visual map of the repo with all the commits in all the branches

One of my standbys is outside of the editor/IDE though. If you have Windows, [Git Extensions](https://gitextensions.github.io/) is a great option. It is an open-source, full GUI for Git that provides 99% of the available functionality of git in an easy point and click interface and visual layout of branches, commits, and files.